# Vector font for suetterlin

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I want to use the old German "Kurrentschrift" in equations. In LaTeX, this is already integrated in the package `suetterl`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{suetterl}

\begin{document}

\textsuetterlin{A}

\end{document}
```

BUT this isn't a vector font, and now I'm searching for very, very long time to find a suitable vector font which implements all the letters in a similar look.

I found the way to implement other fonts with the package `fontspec`, but till now  I didn't find a suitable font...

It would be great, if someone has a hint for a suitable font, or for LaTeX commands to use `suetterlin` as a vector font (but i don't think this is possible)...

Comment: The [schulschriften package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/schulschriften) contains also a Sütterlin font (SU) - but it is no vector font.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can download an opentype version from `Gutenberg-Labo` [here](http://de.sourceforge.jp/projects/gutenberg/downloads/33862/GL-Suetterlin.otf/). Now the simplest way to use it in text mode is loading  the `fontspec` package and compiling with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. All you have to do to use it is to define a switch and a `\textsuetterlin` command with this code:

```
\newfontfamily\suetterlin{GL-Suetterlin}
\newcommand\textsuetterlin[1]{{\suetterlin #1}}
```

If you want to use it with pdflatex, it will be more complex. Roughly you will have to make `tfm`s with `otftotfm`, type1 fonts with `otftot1` (from the  `LCDF Type Tools`) and use  `autoinst`,`fontools` or `fontinst`to create virtual fonts (`.vf`), font declaration files (`.fd`) to use them with `NFSS`, `.map` files so that pdfLaTeX or dvips can find them, install all these files in the appropriate directories and finally refresh the `FNDB` (MiKTeX) or run `texhash` (TeX Live), and run `updmap`.

**Edit (17/07/2018)**:

It seems the above link is now redirected to another site, and the font is harder to find. Here is a direct link to the new [download page](https://de.osdn.net/projects/gutenberg/releases/33862).

To be noted: the font has now, for some reason, a new name: *GL-GermanCursive*, whereas the old version is always available as *GL-Suetterlin-old*.

Comment: I will use it with LuaLaTex. And your code is exactly what I have found out on my own :)
So i have already a suitable font and can use this in normal text, but the problem I now have  is to use the new font in a $...$-math-environment... :/

Comment: Then you'll have to convert it to type 1 and all the stuff (during some sabbatical year;)), the declare a new math alphabet, hoping you'll not get the 'no place for a new math alphabet  message… It you want to use only a few letters in math, it will a little simpler(at leats to my eyes). Or maybe using `mathspec`?

Comment: The problem with `mathspec` and `fontspec` is in my opinion that you just can replace other font types like mathrm, mathbf etc.

I want to keep them but add a new one, so I will now look at this math alphabet stuff... Converting an OTF to T1 doesn't seem so complicated till now, I already have some pfb and afm-files :)

Comment: `Fontspec` also allows changing the font family. What else would you like to do? As for `mathspec` the main problem in my opinion is sidebearings are not too good; one has to do manual adjustments and that's a big job. I once tried it with `Sabon Next LT Pro` and had to go back to  `MinionPro` for maths (both fonts match rather well, in my opinion)

Comment: @Faekynn Do you have a manual how to have fonts in pdf latex?

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger I'm sorry, I don't. For other reasons also, I compile now everything with LuaLaTex. With LuaLaTex and XeLaTex, all the fonts stuff is much easier, as far as I know. I just googled, maybe this can help: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/Type1fonts/fontinstallationguide.pdf

Comment: The link to the font file is outdated. Anyone has a new one?

Comment: @red_trumpet: I've found the new download page, and edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've now a solution which is easy to use also with pdflatex. With appropriate settings, the bitmap font also looks nice.

The only disadvantage is at the moment, that the bold version with `\pmb` isn't really nice...

```
\documentclass[convert={density=10000}]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsuet} {T1} {wesu}{bx}{sl}
\usepackage{bm}
\pdfpkmode{dpdfezzz}
\pdfpkresolution=8000
\RequirePackage{relsize}    
\begin{document}
\fbox{
$\bm n n$

$\pmb{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathsuet n}}}\, \mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathsuet n}}$}
\end{document}
```

[image: comparison of suetterlin and normal font (medium and bold)]

---

for a redefined version of `\pmb`, [look here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266890/redefining-pmb-for-nicer-results)