# Redefining \pmb for nicer results

Tags: fonts, amsmath, bold

I want to use suetterlin font as a math alphabet (in a bold and medium version).

This is how far I got (without any manual font conversions....)

```
\documentclass[convert={density=10000}]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsuet} {T1} {wesu}{bx}{sl}
\pdfpkmode{dpdfezzz}
\pdfpkresolution=8000
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\fbox{{
$\bm n n$
$\pmb{\mathsuet n}\, \mathsuet n$
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As one can see, the thickness of the lines is similar to the normal alphabet... But the bold Version (made with `\pmb`) is not very nice at the line ends...

I found the definition of `\pmb` in [`amsbsy`](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/math/amsbsy.pdf):

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\pmb}{%
\ifmmode\else \expandafter\pmb@@\fi\mathpalette\pmb@}
```

And the definition of `\pmb@`

```
\def\pmb@#1#2{\setbox8\hbox{$\m@th#1{#2}$}%
  \setboxz@h{$\m@th#1\mkern.5mu$}\pmbraise@\wdz@
  \binrel@{#2}%
  \dimen@-\wd8 %
  \binrel@@{%
    \mkern-.8mu\copy8 %
    \kern\dimen@\mkern.4mu\raise\pmbraise@\copy8 %
    \kern\dimen@\mkern.4mu\box8 }%
}
```

I have got no idea what this code does, but I assume it should be possible to shift the reprinted characters (by redefining `\pmb`) so that the line ends look smoother?

---

A previous version of the question contained the definition of `\pmb@@`, which is only for non-math mode.

```
\def\pmb@@#1#2#3{\leavevmode\setboxz@h{#3}%
   \dimen@-\wdz@
   \kern-.5\ex@\copy\z@
   \kern\dimen@\kern.25\ex@\raise.4\ex@\copy\z@
   \kern\dimen@\kern.25\ex@\box\z@
}
```

Comment: why use pmb at all if you have a bold font (as shown by bm) ?

Comment: but this only works for the "normal" font. my `\mathsuet` already takes the (extended) bold version of of the suetterlin font (which is still very thin), see line 3 of the code: `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsuet} {T1} {wesu}{bx}{sl}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This "w" is how the n looks like in this font ;) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%BCtterlin

Comment: I don't have the font so can't test, oddly texlive has the fd files but not the font? but anyway `\kern\dimen@\kern.25\ex@\raise.4\ex@\copy\z@` just shifts the letter by that amount and overprints 3 times, you can add more of them overprinted by different amounts to try to smooth it off

Comment: I did wonder:-) (or do I mean nonder)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can overprint as often as you like at different offsets to try to get a smoother look (but `\pmb` never looks that great)

```
\documentclass[convert={density=10000}]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsuet} {T1} {wesu}{bx}{sl}

% I get metafont errors from these settings?
%\pdfpkmode{dpdfezzz}
%\pdfpkresolution=8000

\makeatletter
\def\pmb@@#1#2#3{\leavevmode\setboxz@h{#3}%
\dimen@-\wdz@
\kern-.5\ex@\copy\z@
\kern\dimen@\kern.25\ex@\raise.4\ex@\copy\z@
\kern\dimen@\kern.2\ex@\raise.3\ex@\copy\z@
\kern\dimen@\kern.15\ex@\raise.2\ex@\copy\z@
\kern\dimen@\kern.25\ex@\box\z@
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\fbox{{
$\bm n n$
$\pmb{\mathsuet n}\, \mathsuet n$
}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, now I see why I could't change the definition of `\pmb` :o I didn't use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`!

Comment: But it works just fine, thanks!

Comment: Hi David but your code work for my bounty actual question? I will wait your answer. Best regards

Answer (score 3):

In addition to David Carlisle answer, the solution I use now:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=10000}]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsuet} {T1} {wesu}{bx}{sl}
\pdfpkmode{dpdfezzz}
\pdfpkresolution=8000
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{relsize}


\makeatletter
\def\pmb@#1#2{\setbox8\hbox{$\m@th#1{#2}$}%
  \setboxz@h{$\m@th#1\mkern.5mu$}\pmbraise@\wdz@
  \binrel@{#2}%
  \dimen@-\wd8 %
  \binrel@@{%
    \mkern-.1mu\copy8 %
    \kern\dimen@\mkern-.2mu\copy8 %
    \kern\dimen@\mkern-.3mu\copy8 %
    \kern\dimen@\mkern.1mu\copy8 %
    \kern\dimen@\mkern.2mu\copy8 %
    \kern\dimen@\mkern.3mu\copy8 %
    %\kern\dimen@\mkern.4mu\raise\pmbraise@\copy8 %
    \kern\dimen@\mkern.4mu\box8 }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\fbox{
$\bm n n$
$\pmb{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathsuet n}}}\,  \mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathsuet n}}$
}
\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]