# Bold math with siunitx, fourier and amsmath problem

Tags: amsmath, luatex, siunitx, fourier

With this configuration I can't have bold siunitx otherwise than using `\pmb`, but with an ugly side effect :

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Erewhon}[
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
    SlantedFont=*-RegularSlanted,
    BoldSlantedFont=*-BoldSlanted,
    SmallCapsFont=*-SmallCaps,
    SmallCapsFont=*-Regular,
    SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}
    ]

\setsansfont{texgyreheros}[
    Scale=MatchLowercase,% or MatchUppercase
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-regular,
    ItalicFont=*-italic,
    BoldFont=*-bold,
    BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
    ]

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bm}             % Bold math with \bm{}

\RequirePackage{siunitx} % \num{} ...

\sisetup{%
    unit-mode = text,%
%   detect-weight=true,
%   detect-family=true,
%   detect-inline-weight=math,
    locale=FR,%
    %detect-all,% Problème avec euro, inutile
    inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},%
    group-minimum-digits=4,
    text-angstrom={Å},math-angstrom={\text{Å}}
} 


\begin{document}

$\pmb{\SI{2109}{kg}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the actual goal you desire?

Comment: As you see, the result appears twice with a little shift. How to avoid that? Why twice ? Any solution with my set of packages would be great.

Comment: As I understand, `\pmb` is an overstrike macro, so twice is what you get (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266890/redefining-pmb-for-nicer-results, with David's answer that "`\pmb` never looks that great").  I guess my question is , are you trying to get the result you present, but only to look nicer?  And only with `siunitx`, as opposed to all math?

Comment: Only for siunitx ontherwise I use `\bm` but it's not work for siunitx. I read all about siunitx and bold, but nothing works with fourier, I finally tried pmb, but with the result you see.

Comment: The strange (or not) thing that without amsmath package it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[detect-all]` option to `siunitx` and then

```
\let\svSI\SI
\renewcommand\SI[2][]{\bgroup\edef\tmpA{#1}\edef\tmpB{#2}\SIx}
\newcommand\SIx[2][]{%
  \textrm{\bfseries\boldmath\expandafter\svSI\expandafter[\tmpA]{\tmpB}[#1]{#2}}\egroup}
```

in the preamble.  EDITED to automatically group-limit the boldness.  EDITED to work in both math and text modes.  MWE below demonstrates that all the optional arguments to the revised `\SI` function properly.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{article}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Erewhon}[
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
    SlantedFont=*-RegularSlanted,
    BoldSlantedFont=*-BoldSlanted,
    SmallCapsFont=*-SmallCaps,
    SmallCapsFont=*-Regular,
    SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}
    ]

\setsansfont{texgyreheros}[
    Scale=MatchLowercase,% or MatchUppercase
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-regular,
    ItalicFont=*-italic,
    BoldFont=*-bold,
    BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
    ]

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bm}             % Bold math with \bm{}

\RequirePackage[detect-all]{siunitx} % \num{} ...

\sisetup{%
    unit-mode = text,%
%   detect-weight=true,
%   detect-family=true,
%   detect-inline-weight=math,
    locale=FR,%
    %detect-all,% Problème avec euro, inutile
    inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},%
    group-minimum-digits=4,
    text-angstrom={Å},math-angstrom={\text{Å}}
} 

\let\svSI\SI
\renewcommand\SI[2][]{\bgroup\edef\tmpA{#1}\edef\tmpB{#2}\SIx}
\newcommand\SIx[2][]{%
  \textrm{\bfseries\boldmath\expandafter\svSI\expandafter[\tmpA]{\tmpB}[#1]{#2}}\egroup}
\begin{document}

Math mode: $\SI{2109}{kg}$

Text mode: \SI[per-mode=symbol]{2109}{\kg \per \s} not bold $xy$

Text mode: \SI[per-mode=fraction]{2109}[\$]{\kg \per \s} not bold $xy$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Work fine, but not in math mode : $\SI{2109}{\kg}$ is not bold. My example was in math mode, so I thought that it was obvious it has to work in math mode. Sorry.

Comment: @Tarass Please see revision.