# How to write bold italic letter in late presentation slide format?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, bold, italic, boldmath

```
\foilhead{Continuous Galerkin finite element method}                                                                                                                      

\definecolor{hgray}{gray}{0.9}

\vspace{-1.5cm}

\begin{picture}(18.0,16.5)

\put(0.3,16){$\bullet$ {Advection equation in 1D}}
\graphicspath{{\dir/}}
\put(11,14){\scalebox{1}{\input{\dir/1d_domain_continuous_FEM.pdf_tex}}}

\put(0.8,15){Linear one-dimensional hyperbolic convective }
\put(0.8,14){transport problem of
the concentration $c$}
\put(0.8,12.5){$G := {\rm v} \dfrac{\partial c}{\partial x} = s\quad{\rm in}\quad{\cal{B}}\,,$}
\end{picture}
```

I want "s" term in bold italic letter format in the given equation.
I tried with \textbold\textit, but did not worked.
Your suggestions will be helpful.
Thank you.[image]

Comment: \mathbf{\textit{s}} this gives only italic effect not bold one. So it is not working.

Comment: And if you use \boldsymbol{s} using amsmath package?

Comment: First try the bm (boldmath) package.  If desperate, Knuth provides a poor man's bold (\pmb) in the TeXbook (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266890/redefining-pmb-for-nicer-results?r=SearchResults&s=2|40.1442)

Comment: And if you use \boldsymbol{s} using amsmath package? this works. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can load `unicode-math` and use `\symbfit{s}`.

The `isomath` package for PDFLaTeX enables `\mathbfit{s}`.

Another option for PDFLaTeX, mentioned in the comments, is `\boldsymbol{s}` from `amsmath`.  This works better if you load `bm` after every other math package.  (The `unicode-math` package also supports this, if you load a bold math font.)

Answer (score 2):

Here a MWE with the use, for example, of `boldsymbol` to get "s" term in bold italic letter.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[G \coloneqq \mathrm{v} \frac{\partial c}{\partial x} = \boldsymbol{s}\quad{\text{ in } \mathcal{B},}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]